# How to see if data is encrypted

Tags: networking, ssl, encryption, network-monitoring

Is there an easy way to tell if I am successfully encrypting transfers between me and my database? Can I look at the network monitor or something that will tell me?

NOTE: I am new to any sort of network monitoring, and might be missing something entirely obvious. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an application like wireshark and monitoring what network traffic is going between you and your database

Comment: +1 for wireshark, I believe it is the most often recommended piece of software here on serverfault.

Comment: @Zoredache: heh, yeah.  Wireshark is to SF what jQuery is to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - I've looked at some screenshots and I don't see what part is telling me that there is encrypted data?

Comment: What protocol does wireshark say is going between you and the database? What protocol should it be, if it's encrypted?